# SSH on but unable to connect (says only sftp)

Tags: ssh

I'm a novice when it comes to Linux.

Our user was trying to ssh to an Ubuntu server we have at work (since someone left, nobody here knows Linux), but it says `This service allows sftp connection only` (He used to be able to do this) . I've tried to ssh using root and an admin account I created but no luck. I tried restart the ssh but that didn't work either.

What do I need to do?

Comment: Check `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, for a line containing `ForceCommand internal-sftp`.

Comment: Get someone competent to assist, by logging directly into platform (server) and configuring remote-access correctly. *Anything else is just guessing.*

Comment: Hi @muru, thank you for pointing me to the right direction! it's solved now.

Answer (score 11):

This message from `ssh`:

```
This service allows sftp connections only.
Connection to  <host> closed.
```

is typical of this configuration in [`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man5/sshd_config.5.html) on the server:

```
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Ordinarily, you use a `ForceCommand` only within a `Match` block, but without examining the actual configuration file, this is as far as I can predict.

Comment: Thanks @ssh, as muru has pointed out, it is around that part of the sshd_config. I commented it out and the user can ssh now.